statusline expression using variables from statusline
Currently if I use byte offset/column offset the values are base 1, I would like them to display in base 0. I have tried the following statuslines with no success.
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=[DEC=\%03.3b][HEX=\%02.2B][POS=%{04o-1},%04c][%p%%]
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=[DEC=\%03.3b][HEX=\%02.2B][POS=%04%{o-1},%04c][%p%%]
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=[DEC=\%03.3b][HEX=\%02.2B][POS=%04%{%o-1},%04c][%p%%]
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w%=[DEC=\%03.3b][HEX=\%02.2B][POS=%04o-1,%04c][%p%%]

All give some form of "variable undefined or bad expression" making me think that performing math on a variable prior to formatting might not be possible? I have seen some examples where people call functions and do logic within those but I am not sure what the file offset variable is called or even really how to define a function, hoping I dont need to dig down that rabbit hole to solve this.

The document at :help statusline describes the (only) possible ways to configure your statusline using the builtin option. There's no facility for computing values based on the expansion of a particular item. There are 2 facilities for using arbitrary expressions to compute statusline text; one that should produce the text to insert %{}, and another that should produce a string of statusline items which will be (recursively) interpreted %{%%}.
In this particular case, you probably want to do something like
%{line2byte('.')+getcurpos()[2]-2}

The line2byte('.') function (found following links from the o item: +byte_offset -> :help go -> line2byte()) gets you the byte position at the start of the line. Then getcurpos() returns a list of items including col, item 2, which is the byte position in the current line (with the first column as 1): this also incidentally includes the extra +1 we subtract out.
Note however that go and :goto use the same 1-based counting as the statusline's %o, so that could get confusing.
AFAICT there is no single function that returns the position computed by %o in the statusline.

I see great building blocks!  so... how does the answer translate into a plugin vimscript snippet?  Side note: I was looking at vim-statusline-generator website, but they seem more permanent to me.

I’m not sure I understood the question @JohnGreene, but I think you replace %o with the text here in your statusline code?
